# We take number $k,l$ from two sets - what is expected value of number $l$?

Tags: probability

We take number $k$ from set $\left\{1,2,\dots,n \right\} $ and then we take number $l$ from set $\left\{1,2,\dots,k \right\} $. Let $E_n$ be expected value of number $l$. Compute:

1. $E_2$
2. $E_3$
3. $E_4$
4. $E_5$

I have computed it and I received:

1. $E_2 = \frac{5}{4}$
2. $E_3 = \frac{3}{2}$
3. $E_4 = \frac{7}{4}$
4. $E_5 = 2$

It was quite easy but very long. Maybe exist faster way to compute it?

As we can see:

$$E_3 = \frac{3}{2} = \frac{6}{5}E_2 \\
E_4 = \frac{7}{4} = \frac{7}{5} E_2 \\
E_5 = 2 = \frac{8}{5}E_2$$

So I suppose that for all $n \ge 3$ we have $E_n = \frac{n+3}{5} E_2$ but I have no idea how can I prove it exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way of calculating this is to use the notion of conditional expectation.

For a given value of $k$, $l$ has expected value 
$$\frac{1+2+\cdots+k}{k} = \frac{k(k+1)/2}{k} = \frac{k+1}{2}.$$
But $k$ itself is equally likely to have values $1, 2, \ldots, n\ $
and thus has average value
$$\frac{1+2+\cdots+n}{n} = \frac{n(n+1)/2}{n} = \frac{n+1}{2}.$$
Therefore, the average value of $l$ is
$$\frac{\displaystyle\frac{n+1}{2} + 1}{2} = \frac{n+3}{4}.$$
Thus, $$E_n = \frac{n+3}{4} = \frac{n+3}{4}\times \frac{4}{5}\times \frac{5}{4}
= \frac{n+3}{5}E_2.$$

Comment: +1. And this method yields immediately the average value of the number obtained after *three* iterations, or after any number of iterations.

Comment: Why does this work? For a given $k$, you calculate the expected value for $l$, then plug in the expected value of $k$, but the expected value for $k$ may not even be an integer. It is an elegant solution, but I'm not sure why it works out so nicely.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese You calculated $\displaystyle E[X]=\sum_i\sum_j i\cdot p_{X,Y}(i,j)$ while I used $$\begin{align}E[X]&=\sum_i\sum_j i\cdot p_{X,Y}(i,j)\\&=\sum_j p_Y(j)\sum_i i\cdot\frac{p_{X,Y}(i,j)}{p_Y(j)}\\&=\sum_j p_Y(j) \sum_i i\cdot p_{X\mid Y}(i\mid j)\\&= E[ E[X \mid Y] ]\end{align}$$ to arrive at the same answer. In many cases, finding the conditional expectation first and then computing the unconditional expectation is easier than computing the unconditional expectation directly.  Hope this answers your question.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese  The first line in my comment above should have read "You calculated $\displaystyle E[X] = \sum_i i\cdot p_X(i)$ by first computing $\displaystyle p_X(i) = \sum_j p_{X,Y}(i,j)$ while I used..."

Comment: That's excellent.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $P(l = l_0 \mid k = i) = 0$ for $i < l_0$ so

\begin{align*}
P(l = l_0) &= P(l = l_0 \mid k = l_0)P(k=l_0) + \dots + P(l = l_0 \mid k = n)P(k=n)\\
&= \frac{1}{n}[P(l = l_0 \mid k = l_0) + \dots + P(l = l_0 \mid k = n)].
\end{align*}

If $k = i \geq l_0$, $P(l = l_0 \mid k = i) = \dfrac{1}{i}$ so $P(l = l_0) = \dfrac{1}{n}\displaystyle\sum_{i = l_0}^n\frac{1}{i}$. Then the expected value is

\begin{align*}
E_n &= \sum_{l_0 = 1}^n l_0P(l=l_0)\\ 
&= \sum_{l_0 = 1}^nl_0\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=l_0}^n\frac{1}{i}\\ 
&= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{l_0=1}^n\sum_{i=l_0}^n\frac{l_0}{i}.
\end{align*}

Now note that we can rewrite replace the double sum $\displaystyle\sum_{l_0=1}^n\sum_{i=l_0}^n$ with the double sum $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{l_0=1}^i$. To see this note that generally we have

\begin{matrix}
\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=i}^na_{ij} &= & a_{11} &+ & a_{12} &+ & a_{13} &+ & \dots &+ & a_{1n}\\
& & &+ & a_{22} &+ & a_{23} &+ & \dots &+ & a_{2n}\\
& & & & & & & &\\
& & & & &+ & a_{33} &+ &\dots &+ &a_{3n}\\
& & & & & & & & & &\\
& & & & & & & & \ddots & & \vdots\\
& & & & & & & & & &\\
& & & & & & & & &+ & a_{nn}\\
& & & & & & & & & &
\end{matrix}

and

\begin{matrix}
\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^ja_{ij} &= & a_{11} & & & & & & & &\\
&+ & a_{12} &+ & a_{22} & & & & & &\\
& & & & & & & & & &\\
&+ & a_{13} &+ & a_{23} &+ & a_{33} & & & &\\
& & & & & & & & & &\\
& & \vdots & & \vdots & & \vdots & & \ddots & &\\
& & & & & & & & & &\\
&+ & a_{1n} &+ & a_{2n} &+ & a_{3n} &+ & \dots &+ & a_{nn}.
\end{matrix}

Then we have

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{l_0=1}^i\frac{l_0}{i} &= \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i}\sum_{l_0=1}^il_0\\ 
&= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i}\frac{i(i+1)}{2}\\ 
&= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i+1}{2}\\
&= \frac{1}{2n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^ni + \sum_{i=1}^n1\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2n}\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2} + n\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2n}\frac{n^2 + 3n}{2}\\
&= \frac{n+3}{4}.
\end{align*}

Now note that your relationship $E_n = \frac{n+3}{5}E_2$ simplifies to the above expression when you replace $E_2$ with $\frac{5}{4}$.